# Stop pushing data in elasticsearch initiate by logstash "exec" plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am very new to elasticsearch stuck in a problem. I have made a logstash configuration file named test.conf which is as follows :-

```
input
{ 
    exec
    { 
        command => "free"interval => 1
    }
}


output
{
    elasticsearch 
    { 
        host => "localhost"protocol => "http"
    } 
}
```

Now I execute this config file so that it will start pushing data in elasticsearch every 1 sec by following command :-

> $ /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f test.conf

I m using kibana to display data inserted in elasticsearch.
Since the data is keep on adding into elasticsearch every second I am not getting how to stop this data insertion job. Please help me out.

Comment: Just stop the Logstash process?

Comment: @MagnusBäck Logstash is not running when I do $ 'sudo service logstash status' it gives me logstash is not running.

Comment: Any Logstash processes running according to `ps aux | grep logstash`?